# Run PowerShell from Azure DevOps

Tags: sharepoint, azure-devops

I have a task: to install solution (wsp) on remote machine using Azure DevOps Pipelines.

I have folder with *.wsp. And I have a PS-script. If I do it manually on this machine it works fine. No errors.

But when I use Azure DevOps I have a message:

```
Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 5.
At C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1:1 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
```

At the very beginning of my PS script I have this:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
```

I need it, because I use Uninstall-SPSolution, Remove-SPSolution, Add-SPSolution and Install-SPSolution cmdlets inside script.

I've tried to add

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
```

to "profile.ps1", I've tried to run powershell inside powershell. Again and again error is the same. I don't understand how to fix it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNM7R.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTiWs.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA6tU.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK9kq.png

Comment: Would you be able to provide a screenshot of the PowerShell step in your pipeline and the beginning of your PowerShell script?

Comment: Images attached.

Answer (score 0):

Try preceding your command with `Get-PSSnapIn`:

```
if (Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell") {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
}
```

Comment: Here is result:

`[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'c:\agent\_work\_temp\78afcb5e-4bf4-43a5-b7a9-18e623fcde84.ps1'"
2021-02-28T09:41: Transcript started, output file is C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\Documents\PowerShell_transcript.mu1Pd_Mk.txt
2021-02-28T09:41:Get-PSSnapin : No Windows PowerShell snap-ins matching the pattern 'Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell' were found. Check 
2021-02-28T09:41: the pattern and then try the command again.`

Answer (score 0):

> Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 5.
> At C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1:1 char:1

Based on the error message, when the powershell execute the ps file, it get the error.

In Auzre Devops Powershell task, it will use the powershell.exe from `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.

The exe path you use to execute the powershell file is different from the default.

You could run the following command in azure devops:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Get-PSSnapin -Registered
```

and

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Get-PSSnapin -Registered
```

You can check if the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell` exists.

Then you could use the correct powershell.exe path to execute the  ps file.

For example:

```
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "path/xx.ps"
```

Comment: Get-PSSnapin : No Windows PowerShell snap-ins matching the pattern 'Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell' were found.